# Python: Transpose data to create a record for each month between two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, numpy

I have a dataset like the below:

```
Category    Date 1     Date 2 
a         2017-01-01  2017-08-01
```

What I want to be able to do is to transpose this data so I have a record for each month between the two dates
e.g.

```
Category Date
a        2017-01-01
a        2017-02-01
a        2017-03-01
.....
a        2017-08-01
```

I need to do this in python and my data is already in a pandas dataframe. Dates are in datestamps format YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a comprehension with `pd.date_range`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[c, d] for c, d1, d2 in df.itertuples(index=False)
     for d in pd.date_range(d1, d2, freq='MS')],
    columns=['Category', 'Date']
)

  Category       Date
0        a 2017-01-01
1        a 2017-02-01
2        a 2017-03-01
3        a 2017-04-01
4        a 2017-05-01
5        a 2017-06-01
6        a 2017-07-01
7        a 2017-08-01
```

---

If you have more than 3 columns and you want just `Category` and `Date`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[c, d] for c, d1, d2, *_ in df.itertuples(index=False)
     for d in pd.date_range(d1, d2, freq='MS')],
    columns=['Category', 'Date']
)
```

The `*_` unpacks the rest of the tuple.

---

Otherwise, we could trap the entire tuple and just grab the bits we need.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[t[0], d] for t in df.itertuples(index=False)
     for d in pd.date_range(t[1], t[2], freq='MS')],
    columns=['Category', 'Date']
)
```

Comment: Love this concept. Having issues in execution. Current error message  line 29, in <listcomp>
    [[c, d] for c, d1, d2 in df.itertuples(index=False)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: First thing is that this assumes 3 columns.  Second, did you include `index=False`?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, I have included index=False. My actual data does have more than 3 columns is that what would be causing the issue?

Comment: I assumed 3 columns and therefore `c, d1, d2` is attempting to unpack those 3 columns.  If you want just the columns in the result you've shown, then I can throw away the rest by unpacking them into a variable `_` by including `, *_` at the end of that unpacking.

Answer (score 3):

I Am not sure about the datetime format it is m-d-y or d-m-y ...also you can replace the `resample('D')` to `resample('MS')` get the month start.

```
df.melt('Category').set_index('value').resample('D').first().ffill().drop('variable',1)
Out[31]: 
           Category
value              
2017-01-01        a
2017-01-02        a
2017-01-03        a
2017-01-04        a
2017-01-05        a
2017-01-06        a
2017-01-07        a
2017-01-08        a
```

Change to `MS`

```
df.melt('Category').set_index('value').resample('MS').first().ffill().drop('variable',1)
Out[40]: 
           Category
value              
2017-01-01        a
2017-02-01        a
2017-03-01        a
2017-04-01        a
2017-05-01        a
2017-06-01        a
2017-07-01        a
2017-08-01        a
```

Comment: Hi Wen, thanks. I have updated my question with dateformats. With your solution where do I specify which date field is the one to  transpose off....

Comment: @smb no worry , I provide both of them :-) , and better accept Pir's answer